# can't find a control inside my gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a simple gridview that contains a label in one of the rows.  I'm trying to access that label in the RowDataBound event, but for some reason I keep getting a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error on the line where I am using FindControl.

I've tried using "gvQReport.FindControl", "e.Row.FindControl", and "Me.FindControl" but nothing works.

Am I not doing this correctly?

Thanks!

```
    Protected Sub gvQReport_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
         Dim lblTest As Label = CType(gvQReport.FindControl("lblTest"), Label)
         lblTest.Text = "test Label"
    End Sub


<asp:GridView ID="gvQReport" OnRowDataBound="gvQReport_RowDataBound" runat="server">
     <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Test">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblTest" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You need to look in the current row.

Comment: Looks okay, I would suggest putting a breakpoint on the "Dim lblTest..." line and checking the contents of e.Row.Controls at that point.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Row](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewroweventargs.row.aspx) property of `GridViewRowEventArgs` is the current row, look for your control there instead of the whole `GridView`.

```
Protected Sub gvQReport_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
     If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
         Dim lblTest As Label = CType(e.Row.FindControl("lblTest"), Label)
         lblTest.Text = "test Label"
     End If
End Sub
```